# Foundation 5 re sizes two images in a row

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a full page foundation 5 site that will work on mobile. Everything is going fine except for one issue.

HTML and CSS

```
    <div class="row collapse" id="banners">
    <div id="cityView" class="large-6 columns small-6 columns">
         <img data-interchange="[images/voip_site_top_img_box_left_2014_small.jpg, (default)], [images/voip_site_top_img_box_left_2014.jpg, (large)]"> 
    </div>
    <div id="cityOrange" class="large-6 columns small-6 columns">
         <img data-interchange="[images/vi_site_top_img_right_2014_small.jpg, (default)], [images/vi_site_top_img_right_2014.jpg, (large)]"> 
    </div>
</div><!--End Row-->
<div class="row" id="information">
    <div id="informationContent" class="large-12 columns">
        Content
    </div>


    #banners{

}

#cityView{

    height:inherit;
}

#cityView img{
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:1px;


}

#cityOrange{
    height:inherit;
}

#cityOrange img{

    width:100%;

}
```

When I load this in my browser, the image on the right gets re sized and becomes a few pixels smaller then the image on the left.

I cant recreate it in jsFiddle so here is a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipscreenshot.jpg)

I cant just set the size in the CSS because then on the mobile version the images retain that and are way too large. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the source image dimensions?  They need to be the same exact width or they will not scale together (because their six column containers are always equal width).

Comment: The image on the left is 949 x 362 and the image on the left is 971 x 362

Comment: see my answer below.  Images need to be the same size to scale together, since their containers (that they scale to) are the same width.  You should be using two 960px wide images instead of two images with different widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the images are not the same width.

In your HTML/CSS, both images are contained within equal width fluid containers (e.g. the classes `large-6 columns`).  This means that no matter the viewport width, those two six column containers will ALWAYS be the same size (e.g. 50% of viewport).

In your comment you said "The image on the left is 949 x 362 and the image on the left is 971 x 362".  Since the images scale proportionally to fit their container (`max-width: 100%`), they must be the same width or they will not scale at the same rate because the ratio of image width to container width will be different for each image.

The solution is to cut the images to be the same size (e.g. combine them and then cut that in half so they both have the same width, likely 960px) so that they scale at the exact same rate (e.g. ratio of image width to container width is identical).

I hope that makes sense.  It may be a little confusing to wrap your head around but this is a pretty crucial core concept when it comes to RWD.

Comment: Honestly it seems obvious now. Thank you for the insight. I will change them and accept answer later if it works.

Comment: This sort of thing becomes second nature after a while once you get used to building fluid width sites but there is definitely a learning curve when you're first getting into it.  Glad I could help!

Comment: I changed it, and when I open it up in any browser, it works. Cheers. However, when i open up the project in Visual Studio, I'm getting the same issue. I thought maybe it was just a VS issue but im running Apache server as well. When i tried it on their, I had the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit. It was my ms webconfig file. Once removed it worked fine.